# Why was my PHP indentation question closed as "opinion-based" while another wasn't?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm refering to my question, [How to properly indent PHP with echoes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008754/how-to-properly-indent-php-with-echoes/), which was closed as opinion-based.

The question is pretty straight-forward: *How to echo a lot of stuff using PHP **and** remain readability of the code?* I understand that this can be interpreted as opinion-based, as readability is not actually measurable and depends on the person.

However I have also linked some other questions on similar topics, which seem to be good questions. Take a look at [How to properly indent PHP/HTML mixed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155799/how-to-properly-indent-php-html-mixed-code). The question has 10k+ views, 32 upvotes and has been stared 8 times. However it is completely a matter of personal preference on indentation (which can start long discussions).

Just as this question's author I was looking for a way to create code in a consistent manner. I can just not find a difference between our questions bases. Why is his question a popular, stared, upvoted one, while mine is a closed and downvoted one?

Please tell me so I can ask better questions in the future.

Comment: That question is too-old, almost __5__ years old. At that time, community wasn't that strict. But, now a days, community is very strict on _what kind of questions to ask_.

Comment: I just voted to close that old question as opinion-based. Once it's closed, we should delete it too, because it serves as a bad example of current question guidelines, as demonstrated by the original poster, and the information it contains is not so useful that we absolutely must keep it around.

Comment: Someday, people will learn to read the rules instead of always having to learn by example. When that day comes, we will be able to have nice things.

Comment: @CodyGray I doubt that day will ever come.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'm conflicted about this one.

We do not allow open-ended questions where the only possible answers are rooted in personal opinion, rather than expert advice. There are very good reasons for this rule, but I won't rehash them here.

But there is (or at least there needs to be) some leeway allowed for questions that *appear* opinion-based to non-experts but can actually be thoughtfully and constructively answered by experienced developers.

[Like DroidDev says in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258153/why-was-my-php-indentation-question-closed-as-opinion-based-while-another-wasn#comment34713_258153), it is important to note the dates of the two questions. Yours was asked very recently, when the "no opinion-based questions" rule was in full effect, [clearly presented in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). The other one was asked way back in 2009, when the site was still in its infancy and the rules were still being worked out. We experimented with allowing practically any type of question, found that didn't work so well, and went back to the drawing board to clarify the rules. You will therefore occasionally stumble across questions that were asked many years ago, when the rules were very different, but would not be allowed today if they were asked again. I know that's confusing, but what's the alternative? Delete all the old questions? Some have advocated for that, but I think it aims towards a foolish consistency. The rules are not so difficult to understand that we have to delete useful content.

But the problem is slightly more complex than that. The old question managed to attract some fairly decent answers. Yours, on the other hand, quickly accumulated a bunch of crappy ones. They have since been deleted, but were presumably visible at the time when people were voting to close your question, and undoubtedly influenced their decision to close.

You see, the reason we tend to discourage opinion-based questions is because they attract lousy answers. Yours appeared to be proving that that fear was well-founded. A major reason for closing questions is to prevent them from attracting many low-quality answers.

I've voted to re-open. Maybe I'm biased by some of the recent complaints here on Meta about overzealous closures, but I think this one is borderline. I'd rather focus on closing the obvious garbage.

Note that [there are good ways to ask subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Do consider revising the question with these guidelines in mind.

Comment: Personally, I didn't find the answers on the old question to be ***that useful***, so much so that we must absolutely keep them around, though I agree that they weren't poor answers either. Also, quite frankly, you can easily solve the HTML output formatting problem by running it through a tool that automatically formats HTML. Many text editors and IDEs can do this.

Comment: @cup I don't find anything in the [php] tag useful. That doesn't mean others can't find value. There's no pressure *not* to keep them around, unless they are harming the site. These are far from that threshold. And yes, use an auto-formatter would be an answer to the question. Not a very good one, but an answer.